# Can apache-jmeter check the return value of a URL for a correct response?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jmeter

The set up for apache-jmeter allows for a URL to be sent to a web-server on multiple threads.  I'm interested in first determining if the response codes are 200-500 and then whether the returned content is the expected content.  Is this detailed configuration possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe so from what it states [here](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

Answer (score 9):

Yes it does. You simply need to add two Response Assertions to your HTTP Sampler.

One which checks the Response Code, and a second which checks the response message.

Whether these passed or failed will then be visible in the Summary Report.